# Epiphany browser v45.1 always renders blank pages web sites under specific user account

Tags: epiphany, user, web-browser

This problem only happens under a new user profile that I have created. There are three other accounts on the system, both admin and std users where epiphany will render pages correctly. I have tried deleting and recreating the account, no change.

Any futher troubleshooting tips appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution after *months* of this issue driving me crazy. I wish I could link the original post to credit the author but I can't find it at the moment.

The problem is corrupted flatpak permissions for the app, and the fix is straightforward. Install the [Flatseal](https://flathub.org/apps/com.github.tchx84.Flatseal) app via AppCenter. Open the app and select the Web (Epiphany) application on left navbar. Now click on the Reset button on the upper right to fix the application permissons.

Epiphany should now be able to render pages again.